# <p> tag font size not working as expected

Tags: html, css

Why does "COL1" & "COL2" appear in larger font that "P1TEXT" & "P2TEXT" ?

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2.0em;
}
p {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 0.6em;
}
```

```html
 <h1>H1 TEXT</h1>
<p>P1 TEXT</p>
<p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>COL1</th>
      <th>COL2</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</p>
<p>P2 TEXT</p>
```

Comment: <th> is overriding the <p> style. whatever the table heading (th) font size is, is greater that .6em. Try adding a style from th that should clear it up.

Comment: Why in the world are you putting a `<table>` inside a `<p>` tag? Learn to HTML, please.

Comment: `* { font-size: 100%; }` to set the text size for all tags to 100%. after you can set your own size for tags you want.

Comment: <p></p> is for inline elements but tables are block elements. it is the basic HTML. If you are beginner try to validate your HTML with https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 4):

The end tag for the `p` element is optional, and tables are not allowed inside paragraphs.

Consequently the table implicitly ends the paragraph and the p end tag is dropped as invalid (which would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)).

The table is not inside the paragraph. You then have only the browser default CSS applying to the table cells.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<p>` is being superseded by the `<th>` do not put a table in a `<p>` tag though... that's just the basics. If you absolutely have to have your `<th>` as a normal blue text, here's how you would do it. Although, I would NEVER recommend this.  are designed to be bold... That's why we have them, if you want it to be normal, use `<td>` if you really want, you can throw a `<p>` INSIDE the `<th>` tag, as I show in Col 3. But again... not recommended, Use `<span>` or `<td>` or even `<p class="IDontKnowHtml">` if you need different cells to have different colors.

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2.0em;
}
 p, th {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1>H1 TEXT</h1>
<p>P1 TEXT</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>COL1</th>
      <th>COL2</th>
      <th><p>COL3</p></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
<p>P2 TEXT</p>
```